# "Specified request cannot be processed." when making any async/bulk REST API call in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, bulk-products-update, async

I have Magento Open Source 2.4.0 with PHP 7.4 and RabbitMQ 3.8 set up in `app/etc/env.php`:

```
'queue' => [
    'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 0,
    'amqp' => [
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => '5672',
        'user' => 'magento',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'virtualhost' => '/'
    ]
],
```

I ran `setup:upgrade` multiple times since adding this configuration. I have all queues except `async.operations.all`:

```
$ php7.4 bin/magento queue:consumers:list
product_action_attribute.update
product_action_attribute.website.update
exportProcessor
inventory.source.items.cleanup
inventory.mass.update
inventory.reservations.cleanup
inventory.reservations.update
media.storage.catalog.image.resize
codegeneratorProcessor
inventory.reservations.updateSalabilityStatus
inventory.indexer.sourceItem
inventory.indexer.stock
media.content.synchronization
media.gallery.synchronization
```

In another Magento installation, that `async.operations.all` queue appeared the first time I created a bulk request, so I’m not worried here.

I’m making a PUT `/rest/es/async/bulk/V1/products/bySku` (`es` is my store code) with the following JSON payload:

```
[{"product": {"sku": "some_sku_here", "name": "new name"}}]
```

I get a 400 with "`No se puede procesar la petición especificada.`", which [is](https://github.com/Magento2Translations/language_es_es/blob/954e9358de18c24d3a32087fe3647109190b690e/es_ES.csv#L6192) Spanish for "`Specified request cannot be processed.`".

Whatever the JSON body I use, I always get this error. I have no issue on the non-async/bulk endpoints (for example `/rest/es/V1/product/some_sku_here`).

I’ve checked RabbitMQ credentials but they’re correct. I can connect using the credentials and host/port above. I’ve not found anything on the Internet that matches my issue.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one day of searching the Internet, I finally found the answer 6 minutes after asking this question:

This is what I had in `app/etc/config.php`:

```
    'Magento_WebapiAsync' => 0,
```

Enabling the module with `bin/magento module:enable Magento_WebapiAsync` then `setup:upgrade`/`setup:di:compile` fixed my issue.